# I cannot make a Installation USB

Tags: installation, usb, startup, disk, make

for some reason I cannot make a installation USB from my system already working, I have tried two different USB's formatted them, but still the "make startup disk" is still faded out!! whiuch I don't understand at all, what could be wrong, please don't make the answer too complicated, as I am not at all into computers and programming, is there a really easy way to solve the problem ?
Thanks you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try "unetbootin".

```
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```

Hope this will help you if I didn't misunderstand what you mean.